# Loading trained BERT models locally in Pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pycharm, bert-language-model

I am working on a project that have to train a Bert model myself, and later adapts that into Pycharm for GUI and more logic. It's a binary classification model. I wrote the script, and successfully trained a Bert model in Google Colab. I did it by

```
trainer.save_model(models)
```

It generates a file named `bert-damaged-classification` with the following three files:

[image: files it attached]

Now, I want to see if this model produces the same result as my Google colab script. Here is the code:

```
config = BertConfig.from_json_file("models/bert-damaged-classification/config.json")
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(os.path.dirname('models/bert-damaged-classification/.'))
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-damaged-classification')

# Below is some random inputs I used for testing.
inputs = ["aaaa, bbbb aaccc vvakejdhqiuwdh92d7h2qdqwss!!"]
outputs = model(**inputs)
predictions = torch.argmax(outputs.logits, dim=1)
print(predictions)
```

It's giving me this error:

```
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'models/bert-damaged-classification'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'models/bert-damaged-classification' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant files for a BertTokenizer tokenizer.
```

I tried changing that tokenizer line to pointing to both `.bin` files in my model, but still it does not work.

Update: I discovered an error, that `from_pretrained` only takes os.path objects. I updated the error message and my code above.

Comment: Did you retrain the tokenizer? If not, I assume you would re-use the tokenizer from whatever model you based this off of.

Comment: I'm kind of expecting to see a "vocab.txt"  file in that folder. Did you do a `tokenizer.save_vocabulary()`?

Comment: @NickODell How can I re-use the tokenizer? Is there a library function that does so?

Comment: @JaytheInj How did you load it initially when you were re-training the model?

Comment: @NickODell It's based on the `config.json` shown above: `config = BertConfig.from_json_file("models/bert-damaged-classification/config.json")`. Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: @JonSG I have added the text file I used to train the Google Colab data. How to incorporate that in my code?

Comment: If the vocab.txt is in that model folder then I think your current code should get you past that error.